# Can ray of light reflect from another ray?

Tags: faster-than-light, time-travel

Consider three light rays 2 parallel 1 perpendicular and source of the perpendicular ray is in between other two.
If ray of light reflect from the other two rays then it must be like standing in front of 2 parallel plane mirrors(infinite mages)
The intention of performing this is that considering the particle nature of light, the reflected ray will hit different particle every time because by the time it gets reflected and come back,the particle which it hit before would have gone $Ct$ distance,thus we might enter the 4th dimension ie time axis.
I know this is totally imaginative, but if we are able to do so, we will be able to do many great things (like slowing time),tough it will be very very tough.

Comment: No, a ray of light can't reflect from another ray of light. [Photon-photon scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-photon_physics) can occur at exceedingly high energy densities, but even this wouldn't cause reflection in the way you describe.

Comment: can this be done in any other way, instead of light ray. The objective is to get speed more then or equal to  that of light and must follow reflection laws?

Comment: No, sorry, you can't violate relativity through 'tricks' - you need to accept that Einstein was right.